# Changing image colors and adding layers?

Tags: javascript, image

First thank you for reading and in advanced for answering.

I am in the process of creating a message board based canine role-playing game. I'm researching and practicing and creating first drafts. So far I have everything I need for the map, forum, front end. I'm using html, css, js, and php. I have hosting with a database and I've been able to successfully create a database, call and input data.

So the part I'm stuck with trying to learn is the character creation page. I want users to be able to customize an image of a canine I've drawn by choosing a base coat color, eye color, and skin color from a drop down each and then that reflect on the image. Then to be able to further make the canine unique by adding markings. I've explored SVGs and it's just not what I want to do, unless it's the only way? But I still don't understand how to make the dropdown and adding/changing opacity of layer (marking) reflect on the image and save as a new image to the website.

So in short, can someone point me in the direction or show me a small example on how to make dropdowns and adding layers to reflect on an image? I really really hope this makes sense!